# Is there a way to programatically trigger popups using the operationallayer config?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

I have a widget that queries a group of features, and I'd like to be able to trigger a popup that looks and behaves the same as the one that gets generated when the user clicks on the map. Is there a call to do this in the flexviewer itself?